# SublimeText fails to save file over sftp after apparent timeout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, sublime-text-3, lubuntu

I am running lubuntu in a VirtualBox. In my file manager (PCManFM-Qt) I navigate to

```
sftp://myusername@myremotehost:/mydirectory
```

and open `myfile.txt` with SublimeText. I can edit and save this file without problems.

However, after some time passes (or for example after putting the machine to sleep), whenever I try to save I am greeted with the error:

```
Unable to save /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=myremotehost,user=myusername/mydirectory/myfile.txt
Error: No such file or directory
```

which does not seem to go away until after I restart the entire system. I cannot even re-open the file or any other file from the remote host into SublimeText; instead SublimeText just opens a blank file called "sftp".

I can still open these files with any other text editor on my system (such as gedit and notepadqq) so the problem seems to be with SublimeText.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Likely the connection was closed for inactivity and Sublime Text then remembers that the network path was unavailable. Try when this happens to stop Sublime Text and start it again. In the meantime, save your file locally.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried closing and reopening SublimeText but it does not work - the only fix I have found is restarting the entire system

Comment: What happens if you restart SublimeText to open *another* document from the same directory?

Comment: @harrymc that also opens a blank file with the name "sftp"

Comment: (1) Try a clean install of Sublime to see if the problem involves a plugin. (2) Sublime Text may not be really closing, so check if it keeps running some process in the background that needs to be killed.

Comment: @harrymc (1) I have no plugins installed, and this is from a clean install. (2) There are no background processes that I can find involving SublimeText. I have tried killing all the sftp processes but that does not help either.

Comment: Sublime needs to keep somewhere something that we know is only reset by reboot. Perhaps a file in `/tmp`. You may need to trace which files it modifies.

Comment: Here are the contents of /tmp: https://i.imgur.com/yXlIbVB.png They seem to be empty files. Not sure if there's something I should do there. Is there any way to trace which file it modifies?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428150/linux-track-all-files-accessed-by-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Open a terminal and execute `killall gvfsd`, then use the file browser to re-navigate to the remote directory. (Closing and re-opening any remote files is **not** necessary!)